# IE stopped showing the main slideshow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is a site which I am designing http://ogunsteel.com/eurotech-new/

I am designing this site for last 3 weeks and almost I checked it in 5 browsers Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari. All things were going well but today IE stopped showing the main slideshow of the homepage which shows in all other browsers.

IE shows some javascript errors which I am not understanding.....

Addition:

A strange things happening here when I tried with IE8.....when I load the page using IE8 sometimes it shows nothing and sometimes it shows that the page is loaded but some error and the error is " 'imagearray[...].3' is null or not an object" in tab-home.js Line: 41, Char:1

and here is the error code line of tab-home.js file....

```
if(setting.imagearray[i][3]&&setting.imagearray[i][3].length>setting.longestdesc.length)
setting.longestdesc=setting.imagearray[i][3]}
var slideshow=this
jQuery(document).ready(function($){var setting=slideshow.setting
setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative',visibility:'visible',background:'#444',overflow:'hidden',width:setting.dimensions[0],height:setting.dimensions[1]}).empty()
```

Comment: IE9 is fine; IE7 and IE8 are not showing the slideshow.

Comment: You would be better off posting the relevant parts of the html, css and/or any Javascript and explain how it works.

Comment: Even in IE9, slideshow is not seen, at least for me. But no error reported like in IE8

Comment: Framing the question title more appropriately will help others who seek to help

Comment: I added the problematic code of the javascript file as IE shows that the error is caused for this...

Comment: I added the problematic javascript code for your reference as IE shows that the error in this file...

Answer (score 0):

The error I m seeing in IE8 is

> Error: jQuery is undefined

and the error is caused by hoverIntent.js

I've see the source code of your site and I see the hoverIntent.js is included before the jQuery library JS, and it could be a potential problem.

Place the jQuery before all the scripts which uses the `jQuery` object

Comment: I added some code on the original question which I am getting from IE sometimes.....please see that if you can help with that.....